# Two questions about iterated integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The two questions are **not** related.

1) Suppose that $f_k$ is integrable on $[a_k,\;b_k]$ for $k=1,...,n$ and set $R=[a_1,\;b_1]\times...\times[a_n,\;b_n]$. Prove that $\int_{R}f_1(x_1)...f_n(x_n)d(x_1,...x_n)=(\int_{a_1}^{b_1}f_1(x_1)dx_1)...(\int_{a_n}^{b_n}f_n(x_n)dx_n)$

2)Compute the value of the improper integral:

$I=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}dx$.

How to compute $I \times I$ and use Fubini and the change of variables formula?

Answer (score 1):

Well, (1) allows you to compute (2) with that trick (note your integrand function's even):

$$I^2=\left(2\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2=4\int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy\stackrel{\text{polar coordinates}}=4\int\limits_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int\limits_0^\infty r\,e^{-r^2}dr=$$

$$=-4\pi\int\limits_0^{2\pi} (-2rdr)e^{-r^2}=\left.-4\pi e^{-r^2}\right|_0^\infty=4\pi\ldots$$

Comment: Why it's $I^2=\left(\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2$, not $I^2=\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2$? And I don't see how you used (1)? And is $I=\sqrt{\pi}$ or $-\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: Did you see my comment?

Comment: I see it now, @Ian. Some 4-6 hours ago the site behaved pretty odd (with me). Anyway, I didn't pay attention to that but it doesn't matter: just multiply from the beginning everything by 2 (and thus by 4 within the squared expression)  as the integrand function is even. :)

Comment: Thanks. But $I$ should be $2\sqrt\pi$ or $-2\sqrt\pi$ ?

Comment: @Ian , is your integrand function positive or negative on $\,\Bbb R\,$ ...? :)

Comment: ...haha...i'm so stupid...Thanks.

Comment: Hey I think actually at first you are right. Since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta \int_{0}^{\infty}re^{-r^2}dr=\pi$.